# Spring Security - permitAll() not allowing unauthenticated access

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websecurity

I want to allow access for unauthenticated only to a few paths: /everyone1/something1, /everyone2/something2 and /everyone3/**.
For the rest of the paths, I want only authenticated requests to be allowed.

For now, I have "class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" with:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter(
      jwtUtils, this.accessCookie, this.selectedRoleScopeCookie);

    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable();

    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/everyone1/something1", "/everyone2/something2", "/everyone3/**")
      .permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and().httpBasic().disable();
  }
```

and in "jwtAuthenticationFilter" I set authentication as:

```
  private void setAuthentication2(String username, String someData, boolean authenticated) {
    User user = new User(username, "", new ArrayList<>());
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
    if (!authenticated) {
      authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
    }

    AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(someData);
    authentication.setDetails(authenticationDetails);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
  }
```

Unfortunately, the above configuration blocks every request, both authenticated and unauthenticated.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This method authorizes some paths for authenticated requests. What you need is:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/everyone1/something1", "/everyone2/something2", "/everyone3/**");
}
```

Then anonymous requests can access this path.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
As far as I understand, this will make all the requests to the above paths to be ignored from my custom filter JwtAuthenticationFilter.
This is not a behaviour that I want - I need ALL of the requests to be filtered by this filter.